# wp_generate_attachment_metadata outputting contents of file instead of writing to file

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a form that will add images to the Wordpress media library and everything is going peachy, except for creating additional images at smaller sizes. The output is happening inside the WP_Image_Editor class in the multi_resize function and subsequently the _save function. The call to imagetruecolortopalette seems to be the culprit.

The output looks like this:

```
�PNG  IHDR��<q� IDATx���w�%�u�����{�}��IA$(QL&iR����)[a%J���^����|����G^�u��ʒ쵨d[�LS��3��D�`��ͼ|�����?���t��$e�m�|���+�:�wN�V�}� ��xB��㝣�k��1�w߽(���O?�k�Kh�1�`��:�W����S�C����MӠ�b0��C)����])�1�=���ֶ�{��Z��c8�Whex��)��S��t�t���x�,�X��b< ����W������D��j��1u]3(G�#��t��4�W�9��0Z�]��#��TUM��ІAiP^����_�JO)�NFC�����(��K�b��[^s+?���GSM�F����(LAU5�|y����-eY��k��(�v���9�����(epΡ�B)0ư���ц�p�1���M������0��T>��S[YE{���#�yE���BkMY�-a���R�%km$��};��`@UU���-�y�c=��꺦i��n'/\�Ok�����X;emu����7.Q�cAԾkO�Hl�j�w��"9����w�=*�XM\���L��a.\�4X[QU�z���q���]Di�x��t:ƹ�\�?c�.�q�� EY�6�Oo��yH�i��8稪 �\�~�:�T{�1&֡0Fǹr4M�2k-�ɔ��(˂rP&��#�� ��n�$ ��e��i®q��%�K��v�����I.^�Ą��Zkq�kz���eپ�1EAQV+EQ��=s   �M=��I�6��k�j��F�ё@Q� �^iq�� �K�v���v��]R75�6J��};1F�}�s���¢�����'O�����`LJ�u�������AK(ι����i;MӴ���E���bKp���� ����>�� ~kF�;��E��t�uK�a'��1��`@w�;�L:̕��!/�����>^�IO ��ӮJm��pc-Mc�(EK�iPi����T�>�DY�P�`L���Z�� �J���4
```

Normal Wordpress uploading and resizing via the admin or Gravity forms works perfectly fine, but my function causes the error.

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

```
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
// http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES['image'], $upload_overrides );

if ( $movefile ) {

    // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $movefile['url'] ), null );
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $attachment = array(
        'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $movefile['url'] ),
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $movefile['url'] ) ),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $movefile['url'] );
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $movefile['url'] );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    $result = array(
        'id' => $attach_id,
        'resized' => $resized,
        'test' => $wp_upload_dir
    );

    echo json_encode( $result );

    exit;
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Which version of WordPress are you using? If you disable all your plugins, does the problem still occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify the solution (since it took me a WHILE to figure it out): you have to pass `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` a relative directory path, not a URL path with **http://** on the front.

So instead of:

```
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $movefile['url'] );
```

It should be:

```
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, ($wp_upload_dir['path'] . '/' . basename( $movefile['url'] )) );
```

Note that I used `wp_upload_dir`'s **path** attribute and not its **url** attribute.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my earlier answer. It looks like the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata) has been updated since I posted this a while back.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_generate_attachment_metadata` requires a directory path rather than the file URL which I was passing.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe do not installed imagemegick? because this function use imagmagick for resize pictures to thumbnails try in console:

```
~$ apt-get install imagemagick php5-imagick
```

don't forget restarting apache